# What pins to close a circuit

Tags: gpio

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B.

What is the easiest way to make and break a single connection under program control - just like touching two wires together?

Comment: you can short anything to anything else to close a circuit ... the big question is `what are you trying to do?`

Comment: Just to be clear, I think foxrider's suggestion above is incorrect and could result in you cooking your Pi. Or it might work, but without further information you can't know.

Comment: That comment (now deleted) seemed to imply a GPIO set high could be connected directly to ground without frying the Pi, which is false.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a cheap relay from Amazon (like this one: [Amazon GBP7 for five units](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ARCELI-KY-019-Channel-Module-arduino/dp/B07BVXT1ZK/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=raspberry%20relay&qid=1563550850&s=electronics&sr=1-9)) and use this to switch your signal. Don't try to connect your circuit directly to GPIO without a relay.

Comment: Hi Jonathan，description of your relay is 10+ years out of date.  It mentions PIC, AVR, DSP, Arduino, but how come most popular Rpi is not mentioned? I know PIC and Arduino are MCUs.  But are AVR and DSP MCU or SBC? I have the feeling that the Amazon UK guys do not speak English and do not know Raspberry Pi. -  ARCELI 5PCS KY-019 5V One Channel Relay Module Board Shield For PIC AVR DSP ARM for arduino Relay
by ICQUANZX

( https://www.amazon.co.uk/ARCELI-KY-019-Channel-Module-arduino/dp/B07BVXT1ZK/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=raspberry%20relay&qid=1563550850&s=electronics&sr=1-9 )

Comment: Sorry for the delay replying. The 5V relay shown works fine with the Pi - I have done this many times.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, No worries.  I have been using the relay you are recommending for over a year, and so far so good: RE: RELAY MODULE KY-019 5V Postby tlfong01 » 2018-Jun-02 Sat 10:10 pm
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158#p1323061, What I found surprising is that Amazon UK speaks broken English, and doesn't even mention that their KY019 relay is Rpi compatible, otherwise their sales should at least double by now.

Comment: I guess Amazon don't care how good the descriptions posted by their merchants are...

Comment: Yes, Amazon is selling millions of things, so no time to pay attention to each of them.  BTW, I found Hobby Electronics RALAY5VM description very good.
(1) http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/5v-relay-module?keyword=relay, (2) http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/about-us.

Comment: My pleasure.  BTW, though those York guys at Hobbyist Electronics don't speak Oxford or BBC English, their technical presentation is professional and at the same time hobbyist and newbie friendly.